# Convert HTML Content to image

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiimageview

HTML Content Example : `This is HTML Content.<div>This is <b>BOLD</b> text </div><div>This is <i> ITALIC </i> text</div>`
This is the HTML content which I want to render and place it in a UIImageView and then save this image.
I tried to first render that HTML content and generated a PDF and then convert that PDF into Image but that image is of very bad result. So that's why I am finding some thing that render my HTML content and add into UIImageVIew and than I will easily save that image inside my application memory.

Comment: To `UIImageView` please explain...

Comment: UIImageView specific to Swift.

Comment: Do you want to place that content into a UIImageView? Seems more logic to place it in an UITextView or UILabel...

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to convert HTML content to Image and save it in FileManager.

Comment: And where is the image there? What's your point? You want something like a thumbnail for a webpage?

Comment: Okay, What I understood is you want to render the HTML text in UITextView and then you want to save snapshot of that textView in internal memory. isn't

Comment: @QadirHussain no, isn't like that, because HTML content also contain images and many things more.

Comment: I think lable/uitextview will support the rendering the images too. try my answer

Comment: label is not supporting the images to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution using label/UITextView

set html text to your label.

```
do {
let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(
    data: "<b><i>text</i></b>".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
    options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
    documentAttributes: nil)
yourLabel.attributedText = attrStr
} catch let error {
  print(error)
}
```

to take snapshot try below code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourLabel.bounds.size, 
false, 0);
yourLabel.drawViewHierarchyInRect(yourLabel.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let copied = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // You have to save this content in your internal memory
yourImageView.image = copied // To Preview that Image in your ImageView
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Got this done. But use "UITextView" not "LABEL" because labelview is not rendering images and background is also changed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but you can do so something like rendering HTML in the UIWebView. Then take the screenshot via code.

Comment: I done this already. But the image quality is very poor by using this method.

Comment: What about displaying it in UITextView as a NSAttributedstring and then screenshot. (As said by Qadir above)