# Convert HTML content to UIImage Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimage

Does any one know how to convert HTML Content to `UIImage` I have refer this [Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342226/convert-html-content-to-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it does not help me much

As I search I have to convert HTML content in `NSAttributeString` ad after I can convert it into `UIImage` but still it not work

`NSAttributeString` to `UIImage`

```
static func imageFromString(from text: NSAttributedString) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(text.size(), false, 0.0)
    // draw in context
    text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    // transfer image
    let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image ?? UIImage()
}
```

//HTML to NSAttribute String

```
extension String {
var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error:", error)
        return nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
}
```

Finally I found issue Border is not coming in Image [Refer this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_headings_hr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the text onto a view first. `UILabel.attributedTitle` seems like the right choice for you.

Comment: Thank you for help but how to do it with code i don't understand .may you please explain  me.

Comment: I don't have time, sorry. You need to create an UILabel, add it to a view (`view.addSubview`), use the frame of that label (`label.frame`) as the parameter in your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. If you don't know how to create and add an UILabel, Google it. The rest of the code for drawing a label is included in the answer in the question you linked in your post.